# Angular 6 Refactoring

Tags: observable, angular6, rxjs6

I just updated my app to Angular 6 and all of my observable imports need to be changed to import {Observable} from 'rxjs' instead of 'rxjs/Observable'

Is there a fast way I can do this? Instead of going in every file and fixing the path.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g rxjs-tslint

rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Source: https://update.angular.io

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to modify the existing rxjs code, you can install rxjs-compact package which provides backwards compatibility.

https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/